# Separating audio, JavaScript, CSS, and images in separate directory in Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, web-server, cache

I have a dynamic website, which is running on **Nginx** and **PHP-FPM**.

Is there any performance improvement if images, audio files, css, js files are put into a separate directory?

Here is my current setup:

```
location /var/www/kk/images {
            root   /var/www/kk/images;
            autoindex on;
                   }

location /var/www/kk/js {
            root   /var/www/kk/js;
            autoindex off;

    }

location /var/www/kk/css {
            root   /var/www/kk/css;
            autoindex off;

    }

location /var/www/kk/audio {
            root   /var/www/kk/audio;
            autoindex off;

    }
```

If this is not the best way, can you tell me why and if it's there a better way to do it?

Comment: Hm... do your actually URLs looks like `http://example.com/var/www/kk/audio/file.mp3` and files is located in the `/var/www/kk/audio/var/www/kk/audio` directory?

Comment: location is correct but url is not like that,it is encoded.

Comment: Are you sure? `/var/www/kk/audio/var/www/kk/audio` doesn't look like correct one.

Comment: yes yes you are right..calls are made like file1.mp3 file2.mp3 from /var/www/kk/audio/

Answer (score 1):

there's advantage of keeping static content in separate folder than php scripts. for instance you can set expires header for css/js/images etc by using the [expires](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule) directive:

```
location /var/www/kk/audio {
            root   /var/www/kk/audio;
            autoindex off;
            expires 30d;
    }
```

to speed up page loading time you might consider hosting those assets from another domain... and some day use the cdn in the origin pull mode to give you even better performance.